# ¿Colocar un alias a la URL de mi sistema?

Tags: web, url

Acabo de subir un sistema a un servidor(Linux-Ubuntu) y lo que sucede es que accedo a este mediante el siguiente link (ejemplo):

-> http://45.95.12.51:8080/SistemaPrueba/Login

Y quisiera saber si es posible cambiar la dirección pero que obviamente apunte a esa. Que la URL se vea así.

-> http://www.Sistemaprueba.com/Login o http://SistemaPrueba.net/Login y así infinidad de ejemplos.

Comment: podrias agregar esto en tu /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar BIND para asignar una DNS a tu direccion Ip.

Aqui tienes informacion mas confiable:

[Ir Enlace](https://www.redeszone.net/gnu-linux/configurar-un-servidor-dns-bind-en-linux-ubuntu/)